# How is teacher-forcing implemented for the Transformer training?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, transformer-model

In this part of Tensorflow's tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/transformer#training_and_checkpointing), they mentioned that they are training with teacher-forcing. To my knowledge, teacher-forcing involves feeding the target output into the model so that it converges faster. So I'm curious as to how this is done here? The real target is `tar_real`, and as far as I can see, it is only used to calculate loss and accuracy. I'm curious as to how this code is implementing teacher-forcing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Each train_step takes in `inp` and `tar` objects from the dataset in the training loop. Teacher forcing is indeed used since the correct example from the dataset is always used as input during training (as opposed to the "incorrect" output from the previous training step):

1. `tar` is split into `tar_inp`, `tar_real` (offset by one character)
2. `inp`, `tar_inp` is used as input to the model
3. `model` produces an output which is compared with `tar_real` to calculate loss
4. `model output` is discarded (not used anymore)
5. repeat loop

> Teacher forcing is a procedure ... in which during training the model receives the ground truth output y(t) as input at time t+1.
> Page 372, Deep Learning, 2016.

Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30852#issuecomment-513528114

Answer (score 0):

In the original Transformer paper ‘Attention Is All You Need’, you will notice that the decoder’s input is a shifted version of the target sequence. This shifting is visible at the bottom of the decoder architecture diagram in the paper. This shift is a practical implementation of the teacher-forcing mechanism in Transformers. During training, the target sequence is shifted and used as the input for the decoder, ensuring that the model, at each decoding step, is conditioned on the actual previous tokens of the sequence. While when using non-transformers you need to explicitly pass the truth token and not the predicted one.